# List append in classes

Tags: python, list, class, oop

I am making a [Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(game)) game and I've stumbled across a problem with my `list.append()` method.

Every time a player makes a move I want to append the board (2d list) to my `ex_boards` list. With every iteration of my `for` loop, instead of appending the current board to my list, it appends it and changes every past board to the current one in the list, something like `ex_boards[every index possible in the list] = current_board`. So instead of having every state of the game in my list, I have `n` (len of the list) times the last updated board.

What don't I understand about classes? Also, my list is right below Class Go.

Comment: It sounds like you are appending a reference to the same board. You should make a copy of the board and add that.

Comment: This is one of the most common Python errors, and it's one of the key concepts in Python success.  You are not storing a COPY of the list.  You are just storing multiple references to the SAME list.  Change one, and you change them all.  You need to save a copy (`x.append( board[:])`).

Comment: @quamrana I've tried that with a l = list.copy() but it didn't work, here's how the list looks like being printed on every iteration of my for loop:

Comment: Sounds like you need to use deep copy.

Comment: @TimRoberts I was thinking similarly, but list.copy() didn't do the trick, Your method also doesn't work for me

Comment: Without seeing any of your code, we are just shooting in the dark.  You clearly have a reference vs copy problem, but the fix depends on your implementation.

Comment: @quamrana deepcopy did the trick, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
ex_boards.append(copy.deepcopy(board))
```